# php validation doesn't work

Tags: php, validation

i have this function, it is supposed work, to validate if two passwords match

What is problem with this code?

```
function validatePasswords($myPassword, $pass2) {
    //if DOESN'T MATCH
    if(strpos($myPassword, ' ') !== false)
    return false;

    //if are valid
    return $myPassword == $pass2 && strlen($myPassword) >= 4;
}
```

thanks :)

Comment: This function validates that the password: 1: contains no spaces, 2: is at least 4 characters long, and 3: is equal to the second password. What is it supposed to do? Are you sure the problem is in this function?

Comment: You need to be more specific about what your problem is: "doesn't work" isn't very helpful. An example or two where it doesn't do what you expect would help.

Comment: After disabling the Javascript and entering all the form values I get
"Congratulations! All fields are OK ;)" so it seems to be working fine.

Comment: yah anubhava, i change with replace tool the line <input id="myPassword" name="myPassword"  type="password" /> and it changes the name myPassword. So the problem is that :) thanks. If you reply, i mark your answer correct

Comment: @anubhava: What does javascript have to do with it?

Comment: i deleted my previous comment. If validation of javascript works, it is ignored the php validation

Comment: @Andrew: I disabled javascript because OP asked us to disable JS and test initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with the code you posted.